# is encrypting post data is required over https?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game with unity which sends score to the server running php.
I am using https to send the score, but my server responds to both http and https.
I know https encrypts data so it cannot be altered on the network, but my problem is this: What if someone forced it to use http and then changed the data in the packet such as changing the score.
Is there any way to force the client app to use https only or any other workaround?

Comment: "Is there any way to force client app to use HTTPS only?" - Usually you as a dev would add support for HTTP as a fallback, if you wanted it. You seem to be approaching this as if falling back to HTTP is forced upon you. Perhaps a code example would be helpful if it is indeed being forced upon you.

Comment: Are people going to download your code and host their own server? If not, there's no reason to support http at all. There would also not be any reason why someone wouldn't be able to send/receive data using https from your game.

Comment: i am using AWS EC2 to host my php code

Comment: That didn't really answer any question.

Comment: so basically if i disable http traffic to my server this problem could be solved ?

Comment: While you should indeed push for HTTPS rather than HTTP, I'd be more concerned with actual users of the game changing their submitted scores than something on the network level - whether HTTPS or not, the client is ultimately in their control and you'll need some way of validating scores on your server anyway, eg replaying each move made etc.

Comment: Well, it depends on the answer to the question I asked. If you're hosting the server, you should definitely only support https. If you have ssl set up, there's no good reason to support http as well.

Comment: no my server code is not getting downloaded.
users will only have my game

Comment: If users only have your game, how are they ever connecting via HTTP even if your API is accessible over HTTP? Do you not control the URL the game connects to?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok so i will disable http on my server.
but there is one problem
there is one php function on my server which checks if user have old version of game and sends link of new version and force user to update.
now my problem is if i disable http and old users are using http link in there game.
how can I send them update link.

Comment: And sorry for my bad English,
its not my first language

Comment: @John yes I have that control and i am going to change url to https in my game.
but my Q is.
is doing only that safe.
my game provide winners real money every day so i need to be sure that score is not hacked

Comment: If the client decides if the user has won and should receive real money, then HTTPS is not your solution anyway. The user has full control of their own machine and can purposefully MITM attack the connection, or reverse engineer your software, etc. Even if you encrypt it from the client to the server with your own encryption, it doesn't guarantee that the user hasn't modified your software first. It only protects people from MITM attacks by hackers (unless those hackers install their own certificates on the machine, and route your app through their own server), etc.

Comment: TL;DR of my comment above: SSL doesn't protect you from the end user intentionally interfering with the requests. SSL protects the connection from being intercepted by bad actors.

Comment: As per my earlier comment - I'm in agreement with @John here.  _Especially_ since this is about real money.  The number one rule is You Can't Trust The Client.  You need to validate and verify _everything_ they ever send you, whether over HTTP _or_ HTTPS.

Comment: Indeed. For example, if your application is a chess game, the server should have the board state at the start of the game. The server should record every move and check it's valid. The server should determine the winner and their score. Otherwise, what's to stop me telling the server that I won? The moment your game becomes about real money, people will exploit it, or pay others to exploit it on their behalf.

Comment: so I think i could not create my app,
since its must be running on client side only,
i can not manipulate moves on server side since my games are not like chess.
basically our app have 3 games
like flappy bird,candy crush

Comment: Thanks for help guys.
I think what I am trying to build is unrealistic according to current technology.
btw I am building andriod app,
can pro guard  help ?

Comment: It's still not impossible - take Flappy Bird as an example.  Presumably the levels are generated in a deterministic fashion from some random seed.  You then record the time of each tap on the screen.  Send the seed and the timings to the server along with the score, and "replay" the game on the server - make sure the scores match.  You might also have some logic based around the timings of the taps - you might decide that two taps within 50ms of each other are "impossible" for instance, and invalidate it based on that etc etc.

Comment: i will give it try
thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve this problem by simulating game on server side.
we log all the moves made by player and then run those moves on server and test if score calculated by server is matched with score submitted by player and if not mark player as hacker